# Modsecurity port issue

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, modsecurity

background: For my uni project I would like to locally host 3 virtual machines (1 attacker and 2 different WAF) to simulate the effectiveness of certain web application firewalls under malicious behavior. I set up 2 ubuntu VMs (to host NAXSI and Modsecurity separately) and 1 Kali (to attack)

I have set up modsecurity using the documentation and I am using port 3000 for my vulnerable web application (default for OWASP Juice Shop). When using curl http://localhost/index.html?exec=/bin/bash it is giving me a 403 forbidden (showing that it is active on localhost).

Whenever I try to do this for port 3000 it gives me the details of the page, which it should not if it is active However localhost (port 80) is where Apache2 is the Apache2 Default Page and the web application is on port 3000. How can i set it up so that when I curl localhost port 3000 it gives me an error 403 (signifying that modsecurity is protecting that web application.

Comment: Have you [installed and setup mod_security](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/server/apache/install-modsecurity-apache-module/#ubuntu) properly?  The link also has the OWASP ruleset.

Comment: Yes I have and verified by running the command https://prnt.sc/JyUv2JdRy1Uq and it printed this. The issue is that when running it on the web app address (localhost:3000) it does not print the same. Print screen: https://prnt.sc/Ijrq6c75OE5O

Comment: Have You [configured the port and domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/246445/how-do-i-create-virtual-hosts-for-different-ports-on-apache) in Apache?  See also: [TroubleshootingVhosts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/TroubleshootingVhosts)